# What is wrong with this CNN network, why are there hot pixels?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I'm building a CNN decoder, which mirrors (in reverse) the VGG network structure from Conv-4-1 layer.

The net seems to be working fine, however, the output looks broken. Please note that the colour distortion is fine, it's the the [255/0 RGB pixels] e.g. green that I'm worrying about.

I tried to overfit a single image, but even then I get these hot pixels. Does anyone know why they appear?

[image]

My net:

```
    activation = 'elu'

    input_ = Input((None, None, 512))
    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', bias_initializer='zeros', activation=activation)(input_)

    x = UpSampling2D()(x)
    for _ in range(3):
        x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', activation=activation)(x)

    x = UpSampling2D()(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', activation=activation)(x)

    x = UpSampling2D()(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same', activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this too many times - it's not a problem with your network, it's a problem with matplotlib and how it displays the image. You are probably trying to display a float with range $<0, 255>$. When matplotlib sees `float` type as input, it assumes a range of $<0, 1>$, and thresholds everything outside of that range, and the results you can see.

Comment: Before printing, I do `y = np.clip(y, 0, 255)` and `assert y.dtype == np.uint8, 'Must be uint8'`, so these pixels correspond to [0, 0, 0] to [255, 255, 255] where 0/255 are sometimes interchanged to produce yellow/cian etc.

Comment: Mind sharing the full code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it would turn into a debugging exercise. I thought it's a common problem that has a known reason for happening. I guess the issue is somewhere in the code. I'm partially afraid that I'm stuck in local minima, but I doubt it.

Comment: Trust me, I'll spot your mistake in under 60 second. There's no way a network-related issue results in something like this. It's something with how you process the data.

Comment: Here is the network -> https://github.com/skiler07/mst-tf/blob/master/trainer/MST.py I am implementing a paper. The preprocessing is quite complex. If you wish to reproduce, you can clone master and try running locally.